# Using atoi to fill an array of ints

Tags: c, arrays, atoi

First time asking a question on here. Apologies if there's already threads about this but i had a few searches and didn't quite find what i think i was looking for. I'm very new to C and am working through a few homework exercises for my microcontroller systems class. We're currently working through easy exercises before we get into embedded C and I'm trying to write a program that'll take a line of text consisting of 10 numbers separated by commas and fill an array of `int`s with it. As a hint we were told to use a `substring` and `atoi`. I think i'm close to getting it right but i can't get it to output my numbers properly.

Also i'm not looking spoon fed answers. A few hints would suffice for now. I'd like to try figuring it out myself before asking for the solution.

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    int a[10];
    char str[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}; //contains string of numbers
    int i;
    puts("This prints out ten numbers:");

    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        a[i] = atoi(str);
        printf("%d", a[i]);
            //i'm guessing the problem lies in one of the above two lines
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This is outputting the following:

```
This prints out ten numbers:
0000000000
```

Thanks to anyone that can help!
Chris

Comment: FYI - atoi is deprecated. It still functions but its preferred to use strtol

Comment: @dbeer Turre, but some profs don't keep up to date.

Comment: `char str []` *is* an array of numbers... I think your lecturer wanted the whole comma seperated list surrounded by double quotes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You said that you have to use a line of text separated by commas but you've actually declared a `char` array containing ten (binary) integers. To get that into a string you just need to do this:

`char str[] = "1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10";`

Then you'll need someway to process this string to get each number out and into your array of `int`.

Comment: @MikeD: I thought that was implied by processing the string to get the numbers out :)

Comment: Good to know, atoi processes the string until the first non-numeric character is found.

Answer (score 1):

First off, you should declare a `string` as follows:

```
char str[] = {"1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10"};
```

the `"` made the numbers a whole string. Next, you'll need to tokenize them and using the `<string.h>` library which will come quite handy in this situation.

Here is how you do tokenizing:

define a token buffer first:

```
char* token;

token = strtok(str,",");   //think of it as substring, the part of the str before the comma
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    a[i] = atoi(token);
    printf("%d\t", a[i]);
            //i'm guessing the problem lies in one of the above two lines
    token = strtok(NULL, ","); //this line is also required for tokenizing the next element
}
```

Using the `strtok()` function, you separated the elements between the comas, and got yourself the number strings. Used `atoi()` function to convert them into integers and printed them. You can [see this reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strtok/) for `strtok()` function for better understanding.

Comment: This should be useful! I'll give this one a go. I'd read about the strtok function but we haven't been taught it yet so i didn't think to try it.

Comment: `{"1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10"}` is of type `char*[]`, not `char[]`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in how you're creating the string.
Please excuse my previous answer, I misunderstood your question:

Simply put, the declaration should be as follows:

```
char str[] = "1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9, 10, 12";
```

Next, you can use strtok to separate the string into an array of strings omittied the separator (which is in your case the comma), then pass the array members to `atoi`

Now, why is your code not working?
First, characters should be surrounded by the apostrophes or else the compiler will take the number you pass literally as the ASCII value.

Second, arrays in C like this:
`char str[] = {'1', '2', '3', '4', '5'};` don't mean a comma separated string, these commas separate the ARRAY members, each in its own index and not as a whole string.

Comment: What about '10'?  That is not a `char`.

Comment: I did NOT downvote ANY thing here :(
Don't make assumptions, man..
I was busy doing something else and trying to edit my own question

Comment: well, sry if its a wrong accusation, just seemed suspicious, downvotes immediately, for no apparent reason, but not yours apparently...

Comment: No problem.
Now, to the 'decent' down-voter, can you explain your down-vote with a comment?

Comment: Guys i think i've downvoted accidentally! I tried to click "This answer is useful" but it gave me a message about needing 15 rep points or something before i could do that then set the number to -1. If that' what you're talking about then it was me. Sorry!! To clarify, i found your answers quite useful! oops!

Comment: @ChrisLyttle Downvoting requires 125 rep. It'll take a few more questions or answers before you can accidentally downvote ;)

Answer (score 0):

Your definition of `char str[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};` actually sets
the values of the chars to 1 to 10.

In the ASCII-chart of characters, these are unprintable control-characters.
Writing '1' instead of 1 will set the value to the ASCII-value of 1, which is 0x31.

another mistake is that the commas in your definition only seperate the values in the definition, so the result is a array of chars without any seperation, so 12345678910.

so the correct way would be
`char str[] = "1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10";`

Comment: So what is the difference between using char *str... and using char str[]... ?

Cheers btw! I've tried putting in the ""s around the string but now i'm getting this output:
    This prints out ten numbers:
    1234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890

not quite what i expected!

Comment: aah, just from being used to it ^^
actually, there is not MUCH of a difference...
an array of type char (`char[]`)is different of an pointer of type char (`*char`) in that its pointing address cant be changed

Comment: The main difference is you can change what's in the array, but you cannot change anything in the string if you use `char *`

Comment: are you sure you actually used `char str[] = "1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10"`?

Comment: OK, I see! I'm still trying to understand how pointers work and when to use them.

Comment: Yeah, i tried a few of the different combinations. '1','2', etc and as you'd mentioned. I'll get there yet.

Comment: @teppic: you are right of course, `"string"` is actually a `cons char*`, so a pointer to it cant change the object... in case of `char[]` it actually initializes the array with the given string, so it can be changed...

Comment: @ChrisLyttle: `char s[] = "..."` will copy that string into an array that is allocated in memory for you, but `char *s = "..."` will just point to a string that's been stored in the binary. Although it'll be in memory, you aren't allowed to change it and no storage is allocated. (Cross-post @Legionair)

Comment: @teppic: exactly, nicer explaination 1up

and Edit, changed to char[], for correctness